# Login logic to load a specific user

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to create a login system, but the logic to load user is not working (the error is that it does't varify the password it only varify user if user exist then it will print ('login sucessfull') no matter what the password is can't able to find mistake)

```
class SaveUser:
    user = {}

    def inputUserInfo(self):
        self.username = input('Create Username:')
        self.email = input('Create Email:')
        self.password = input('Create Password:')

    def saveUser(self):
        self.user[self.username] = self.password
        print(self.user)

    def askUserToLoad(self):
        self.enterUsername = input('Enter Username:')
        self.enterPassword = input('Enter password:')

        if self.enterUsername in self.user and self.user[self.username] == self.password:
            print('User Logged in Successfully')
        else:
            print('sorry user not found')

    def runProgram(self):
        self.inputUserInfo()
        self.saveUser()
        self.askUserToLoad()


run = SaveUser()
run.runProgram()
```

Comment: I have fixed the indentation of your code. For future reference, you need to indent *every* line with an *additional* four spaces, not just indent the first line with four spaces. To do this easily, select the *entire* code block and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Anyway, think carefully about the comparison you are doing - you have a simple typographical error. Where does `self.password` come from? How did `self.user[self.username]` get its value? Does it make sense to do that comparison? Where is the part of the code where you ask the user for a password *to log in with*? How do you name the password that was typed in this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up some variables in the `askUserToLoad` method:

```py
if self.enterUsername in self.user and self.user[self.enterUsername] == self.enterPassword:
    print('User Logged in Successfully')
else:
    print('sorry user not found')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are matching the password stored in the `user` dictionary against the password stored in `self.password`. But the password that user is entering at the time of login is being stored in `self.enterPassword`. You should match the password stored in the dictionary with password stored in `self.enterPassword` only then login will be attempted when the password is correct otherwise login will fail.

```
if self.enterUsername in self.user and self.user[self.enterUsername] == self.enterPassword:
     print('User Logged in Successfully')
else:
     print('sorry user not found')
```

Comment: Why check that `self.enterUsername in self.user` and then access `self.user[self.username]`?

Comment: That was a bit typing mistake. I corrected that now. Checking the password against self.user[username] will fail if the last saved username and currently attempting username are different.